# Python tkinter: Can't compile with cmd?

Tags: python, cmd, tkinter, python-3.3, cx-freeze

Well, I have already compiled to programs in .exe with cx_freeze (3.3) but know in cmd it shows me an error:

```
c:\python33\lib\distutils\dist.py:257: UserWarning :Unknown distribution option:
'executable' 
warning.warn(msg)
running build
```

I have already tried to uninstall and re-install cx_freeze but it still shows me this error.

Here is what I'm calling in the command line:

```
c:\Python33\python.exe setup.py build
```

Here's my setup.py file:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable 

setup (
    name = "" , 
    version = "0.1", 
    description = "", 
    executables = [Executable("")] ,
)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you show us whatever you're typing into the command line or whatever any of the setup files are? From looking at the error message, it looks like the issue might be with how you're building the exe

Comment: my command in the smd is :
c:\Python33\python.exe setup.py build

Comment: from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup
    ( name = "" ,
      version = "0.1" , 
      description = "" , 
       executables = [Executable("")] , ) (all is properly intdented